# How to check if JSON output same as JSON postman output in android studio with volley library.

Tags: android, json, android-volley, postman

Can someone help me with this.
Let say I have this example:
Postman give me this json output (for testing only). 
[Postman json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3IHJ.png)

and I have the code for this test in my main application(Using Android Studio).
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8u2b.png)

The code works perfectly fine. However I want to confirm that the response from the code exactly same as the response from postman test. The result can show in terminal or whatever. How can I check for that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply print the response in the onResponse method:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.i(String.valueOf(response));

}
```

Comment: Sir. I still don't get it. Can you help me more? like exactly how should I do it. Thank you Sir! I am a newbie to android.

Comment: On your try block you have response, just do Log.i(String.valueOf(response)); to print the complete json response.